# Why creating a string affect other variables?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code.

```
int *x = somefuction();//return array of two elements
string s;
cout << x[0] << " and " << x[1];
```

This code prints unexpected values. But if I comment out "string s;" row it works fine. What is the reason?

Some function is:

```
int* getRowCol(int l){
int min = floor(sqrt(l));
int max = ceil(sqrt(l));
int area = 100000;
int result[2];
for (int col = min; col <= max; col += 1){
    for (int row = min; row <= col; row += 1){
        if (col*row < area && row*col>=l){ 
            area = row*col;
            result[0] = row;
            result[1] = col;
        }
    }
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: does `somefuction()` return the address of its local variable?

Comment: add somefunction() to problem

Comment: See http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/difference-between-stack-and-heap/ for the difference between stack and heap.

Comment: Standard behavior of a [dangling pointer bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  The std::string constructor clobbers the pointed-to value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to some value that exists on the stack in `someFunction()`. I.e. a local variable. These don't live past the end of the function call.

```
int* someFunction()
{
    int someInts[2] = {10, 20}; // only exists inside someFunction
    return someInts;
}
```

Perhaps you should use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which will take care of allocating memory in a way that is safe to use like this.
It is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to dereference this returned pointer in any way. Your code could do absolutely anything.
Try something like this instead:

```
std::vector<int> someFunction()
{
    std::vector<int> someInts {10, 20};
    someInts.push_back(30);
    return someInts;
}
```